# What, when and will we migrate questions to MO 2.0?

Tags: discussion, migration, mathoverflow

It was [announced on meta.MO](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1416/mathoverflow-20/) that preparations are taking place for the migration of MO to the SE network. In particular this means that we will be able to migrate questions over there, and will receive their "lesser" questions (which are often closed as too localized there).

Most threads discussing research level questions on MSE are from two years ago when the site was conceived, but so much has changed and I feel that we need to bang on this issue again.

I think that need to ask ourselves, should we be concerned with the site, or with the question? If a question has a *much* better chance to be answered on MO, I suppose we should migrate it. On the other hand, we may want to attract experts by showing that we have interesting questions here as well.

> Under what circumstances (except request by OP) should a question be migrated to MathOverflow?

Comment: Questions that haven't received a good answer in a few days are also often good candidates for migration between overlapping sites.

Comment: I'd say by OP request only.

Comment: Why do we migrate borderline CS, Statistics and so on to the different sites - if we wait for the request of the OP?

Comment: @Asaf It's somehow different with MO. There is a decent chance that a migrated question will be closed, and this is OP's risk to take.

Comment: @Lenoid: I think that the communities can decide on a "two pong limit" where the question can be migrated back and will not be re-migrated.

Comment: I'm not sure how SE admin tools work.. Is the migration decision completely one way? I mean, does the MO mods get to accept/reject migrated questions into their site at all?! To prevent a possible closure of migrated question, could we possibly ask that MO mods accept/reject the migration. So we decide on the migration as usual (by flagging, and mods actions), but the migration gets into a pending state awaiting MO mods acceptance. If they reject it, then it stay in MSE. If they accept it, then there's a good chance that it fits there.

Comment: It seems pointless to discuss this without any material evidence. Why don't we wait after a few migrations?

Comment: @Francois: When theoretical CS, or computational sci., were opened there was a discussion after a few moves and then several concurrent threads pointing out that people are not following the convention from previous threads. Since I know that this might be a *serious* (in my opinion, it may be a very serious issue) issue later on, I figured bringing this up before the actual heat is a good idea.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Re-migration is usually not done, creating a chain of migrations leads to all kinds of annoying stuff. But if the question is closed on the target site, the migration is undone. This still doesn't reopen the question on the source site (the assumption is that migrated questions are off-topic on the source site).

Comment: @MadScientist: I see, that is news to me.

Comment: I was waiting for that downvote. I think it is important to disagree with the idea of **having a discussion**.

Comment: @Leonid: I believe, based on my experience, that MO users will be much less likely to close a question if they know it sat around on MSE for a couple days and did not receive any good answers. Thus, I think the risk of closure is much less than you (and others here) assume, as long as every question migration is accompanied by a comment stating how long it remained on MSE before being migrated.

Comment: @Charles: If we are able to migrate then there are timestamps on the posts and it is immediate to see how long the question waited on MSE.

Comment: I actually want my old questions on MO to be moved here because first I got know about MO and only later about MSE which is more appropriate for me.

Comment: To present a possible "reverse case" regarding "people in site W don't hang around in site Z": I have accounts on both MO and math.SE, though I tend to hang around the latter more than the former. SFAICT, questions on [tag:special-functions] (my personal topic of interest) don't get touched much in MO, even though they are ostensibly of the type of questions that are supposed to be on MO. By way of contrast, me, Sasha, sos440, Raymond, and maybe a few other people who deal with things like this, hang around here a lot more than on MO.

Comment: For whatever my opinion counts for: I'd rather that migrations to MO be only done at either a user's behest, or through the usual voting procedure (i.e., have normal users choose (ostensibly, those voters are knowledgeable enough to see what should be here, and what should be there), and mods can only migrate **if** (which I cannot emphasize enough) they are the **fifth** vote to migrate, or because OP has asked them to migrate their question).

Comment: As an addendum, the "migration by voting" can and should only be done after some agreed-upon time has passed. (A week? Two weeks?) This "agreed-upon time" may have to be discussed.

Comment: @J.M. I don't think that model would work well because generally one cannot depend on folks from one site being able to judge topicality on another. That goes both ways here, I don't think that most 10k+ MO folks have general knowledge of what we allow, and vice-versa. The rep/knowledge garnered to attain such privileges does not transfer to knowledge of topicality etc. on foreign sites. But perhaps it could be used to *recommend* (vs. execute) migrations (or, better, cross-posts).

Comment: @Asaf Why do you think that the downvotes to your question represent disagreements "with the idea of having a discussion"? Based on the answers, I think it is *highly* more likely that they represent disagreements with your statement that "If a question has a *much* better chance to be answered on MO, I suppose we should migrate it".

Comment: @Bill: That is merely an example of an opinion. I have not yet consolidated a consistent approach to this. Which is why I wrote "I suppose we should..." rather than "we should migrate it"; note that I also presented the counter argument in the same paragraph, one sentence later. On the other hand, if you read the thread then you see that this is merely raising the awareness of the community to the upcoming issue which may pop up. This is a call for discussion.

Comment: @Asaf I read the quoted sentence as your opinion - which seems consistent with the answer you posted. If that is not the case then perhaps you should edit the question accordingly, and perhaps your downvotes will disappear. I think such meta questions work better if one poses them neutrally, reserving opinions for answers. But that still doesn't explain why you think that the downvotes are against discussion. Why post such extreme speculation? Do you think such speculations are *constructive*?

Comment: @Bill: You quoted them *out of context*. The full context is a lot more careful, and presents a counter argument. I have a hard time believing that someone would downvote for this sentence and would not immediately retract their downvote after seeing the continuation of the paragraph. Why I am making this sort of inference? Because that's how I am programmed. I have absolutely nothing constructive to say on this, so I guess we'll stop now. (Also why do you think *this* discussion is constructive in any kind of way? It's not.)

Comment: @Asaf Ok, I was hoping that you might explain the purpose and reasoning behind that comment. But "that's how I am programmed" doesn't tell me much.

Comment: Just as MSE users can sort questions by activity, posting time, popularity etc, perhaps MSE questions that have high interest but no accepted answer after 2 days can show up in an MO question list. That way MO users won't be bothered by them unless they want to be, and they can quickly view questions that could be suitable for them to answer. We could safeguard the feature by blocking the questions with the (homework) tag and other very basic tags. This is a minimally invasive way to promote cross-pollination whilst keeping good questions here at MSE.

Comment: It seems that the closure of a reasonable question as being too narrow is relevant to this discussion.  There is [a meta thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4936/237) on this question.

Comment: @Joseph: I think that this is somewhat irrelevant to the case. The user in question there has somewhat of a notorious reputation on MSE. There had been several suggestions that he asks some of his questions on MO before, but he continued to insist that his questions are mere trivialities (peculiarly enough, on the same page others insisted that these questions are good because research mathematicians said they are interesting), and therefore he will not write any paper on the topic, any notes, and won't take any suggestion to try MathOverflow. Why? Only he knows...

Comment: @AsafKaragila: How is that irrelevant?  It sure sounds like migrating some of his questions to MO over his objections is exactly what you'd like to do...

Comment: @Noah: It does? Interesting, do lend me your sound system once. I would like to test it. I **suggested** that he may take his questions to MO, where they may be exposed to *more* experts than they are here; both when he was doing AC stuff (where MO has Andreas Blass) and when he is going at topics I have no interest in, but see several *research* mathematicians admit to interest in these questions. I thought that this is one of the criteria for a question being *fitting* to be posted on MO, no? Otherwise, why was there so much commotion in this thread?

Comment: Now it's your *(or someone else's)* turn to suggest that I only suggest that in his case because I have some personal grudge against him. Then it's my turn to say that this is not the place to discuss this, and if you think that I have a personal problem with MK which affects my behavior, feel free to start a meta thread about it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: One of the reasons that there was so much commotion in this thread is that a lot of users think that there is never a good reason ever to migrate questions to MO, and that the only reason we might ever be interested in migrating questions to MO is because MO wants to steal all the interesting questions.  The question that Joseph linked to seems to me to directly contradict a lot of arguments made here (though not by you) and hence is highly relevant to the discussion.

Comment: @Noah: I think that you are misreading the situation. I can't really explain it, but it seems that way.

Answer (score 68):

I think that a sizable supply of *interesting unanswered questions* is a feature, not a bug. They are the only thing that the site has to offer to the visitors who are not trying to get homework done (their own or others'). Remove such questions, and what you have left is a homework hotline of progressively diminishing interest, activity, and quality.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once.

Comment: Indeed, for MSE to prosper we need to *continually* attract new expertise. Migrating (so closing) difficult questions works against attracting such expertise to MSE.

Comment: @Bill, so, m.se is a pyramid scheme?

Answer (score 28):

As far as I'm aware, the set of things that are on-topic at MO is a *proper subset* of the set of things that are on topic here.

For this reason I think questions should not be migrated to MO at all -- a question that MO would accept is one we should not reject in the first place. An exception to this can be made if the asker changes his mind and *explicitly requests* to have his question appear on MO instead. But we should never do that spontaneously.

Comment: Henning, to drive a point from JDH's answer: Suppose a transient user comes and asks a very interesting questions that not a single user on MSE knows how to answer. On MO, on the other hand, there are three or four users who could answer it - all expressing dislike of MSE. Should we migrate this or should I copy the question verbatim to MO, wait for an answer, and post as a CW answer to the original question? The latter makes **no sense** considering the software.

Comment: @Asaf: Sure, if you think preserving the opportunity for this site's users to answer an on-topic question that someone posted on this site **makes no sense**, and also think it **makes no sense** whether potential new users who consider using MSE will find that the most interesting unanswered questions have already been closed, then you're right. I dispute those assumptions.

Comment: Asaf's comment (and several others on this thread) seems to have a misperception about why MO users might not also use MSE.  Rarely is it because people *dislike* MSE.  I like MSE, I'm glad it exists, and I put considerable effort into getting the site off the ground.  But nonetheless, I have a limited amount of time, and as a result I do not check MSE often enough, and so I'd rarely see questions here.  I check MO more often.

Comment: Suppose that questions could be *extended* to MO, as a new software feature; say, there was one copy of the question on each website, and answers and edits on each website were echoed on the other, but voting and comments (and reputation) were kept completely separate. It seems to me that such a feature would answer most of the objections raised, and might also prove useful in other instances (surely MO/MSE are not the only two communities with overlapping domains). Would you support such a "feature request"?

Comment: @CharlesStaats: Yes, I would support such a feature with warmth and fervor; it could mitigate many of the fragmentation problems that arise when SE sites (inevitably) have overlapping topics -- such as also between math and CS. (See also, incidentally, [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4873/questions-asked-simultaneously-on-other-se-sites/4893#4893) from another thread). Not sure that comments would need to be separate, but that's an implementation detail, I think.

Comment: The system message does say "off-topic", but in reality that is not the case, i.e. when a question is migrated it doesn't mean the question was off-topic, it can simply mean that it is *more* suitable for another site. Arguing over the exact text shown there is not productive, if that is the main issue we should ask 
SE to change the message.

Comment: @Charles, I don't think people with be happy with that, an answer posted on MSE can be unwelcome on MO (or vice versa) because they are tailored towards the audience they are directed at. I think a better option would be to have an option that the answers on the target site automatically show up on the source site, but even that can problematic.

Comment: @Kaveh: The point is not which text is shown when the question is deported but whether it should be deported at all. The statement of what is on-topic at MSE is that _we welcome mathematical questions at all levels_, and we should _keep_ welcoming mathematical questions at all level no matter which other sites exist in SE. There is no such thing as a question "more on-topic" on MO, because _every_ mathematical question is **fully** on topic here.

Comment: I thought so. Note that I didn't write more on-topic, I wrote more suitable, and what I  I mean by suitable is based on what OP is really looking for. If it is likely that the OP will get a satisfying answer on another site then IMHO it is not unreasonable to migrate the question (unless the OP explicitly objects to it). I think it is important to keep in mind that the main goal of the OP posting a question is to get a satisfying answer. If the answer is *significantly* more likely to be provided on another site then the migration can be an option. E.g. if a question is left open for a month

Comment: without getting answered, why not migrate the question if it seems likely that it can be answered on another site?  (the idea of collecting unanswered questions and keeping them from being answered reminded me one of xkcd cartoons.)

Comment: @Kaveh: Sorry. There is no such thing as "more suitable" on MO, because _every_ mathematical question is **fully** suitable here. Better?

Comment: If an OP wants to ask the question on MO, then he shall be free to do that. But it is nobody else's business to tell an OP that the question he chose to ask _here_ is one that the members of the site he chose to ask it on _must not be allowed to answer_.

Comment: No one is forcefully preventing people from answering it, generally answered questions are seldom migrated. I think the main case is when the question has remained unanswered for a considerable period of time. In any case, at least it should not be unreasonable to comment in such situations and letting the OP know that the question might get answered on another site.

Comment: @Kaveh: Migration of a question does forcefully prevent people from answering it. That is one of the major technical effects of a migration -- that the software will afterwards reject attempts to answer the question on the site it was posted to originally. This should only happen to questions _that we explicitly want MSE to contain no answers to_.

Comment: @Kaveh: We're not talking about "comment in such situations and letting the OP know that the question might get answered on another site" -- we're talking about _forcible migration_ contrary to the OP's wishes.

Comment: I was referring to your comment below another answer. I don't think people are suggesting migration even in the case the OP objects to it (I agree with you if that is the case). It seems to me that you interpreting posting a question here as an objection to migrating the question whereas often it is simply because of lack of OP's knowledge that it is more likely to get answered on another site.

Comment: Anyway, I think I get your point (though I disagree). I wouldn't mind posting my answer on MO if a question got migrated there. But you seem to dislike that and prefer to only post answers here and I respect that. However I still think that it is reasonable to migrate a question in case it is going to be helpful for the OP. I see answering a question in the context of helping the person who has asked it and I see migration as a reasonable possibility in that context (when a question is left unanswered after a reasonable amount of time, e.g. a week/month).

Comment: @Kaveh: See, for example, JDH's answer. He wants questions to be migrated to MO if he would like to answer them at a MO level -- even (explicitly!) when "the answer is not an answer that the OP appreciates, although the MO community would appreciate it."

Comment: @Kaveh: Again, if the OP wants a MO answer, and considers himself qualified to post on MO, then I have nothing against him going there to ask. But I don't consider that a valid reason to permanently block the possibility of getting an answer _here_.

Comment: I disagree with JDH's sentence also in the same context I explained above. People are free to post new more advanced questions on MO based on those posted here. SE has a feature that one can post an answer at same time as posing the question and it seems to me that is a more reasonable way when one wants to state a nice point. So I disagree with migrating an on-topic question when it is not for the benefit of the OP.

Comment: @Kaveh: One reason I suggest separate voting is so that different answers can come to the top on different websites, which might partially address your concerns in the comment you addressed to me.

Comment: The representation of my position by comments in this thread is not accurate.

Comment: Well, I am sorry that you misunderstood what I wrote. Should I delete that comment since it was misunderstood? The way you are presenting my position is not something that I agree with.

Comment: @JDH: Again, they way I presented your comment was a _verbatim quote from you_: "Like many users, I write my answers for the whole community, not just the OP, and so I would rather that those answers be on MO so that the MO people can see my answer. For many of the questions I have in mind, the answer is not an answer that the OP appreciates, although the MO community would appreciate it. If only the OP mattered, we could just email our answers directly to the OP, rather than posting them at all. "

Comment: Yes, this was a reply to another user who claimed that it would make no sense (in boldface) for a person who answered a question to ever want that question migrated to MO. I  explained that this situtation could easily arise, for a user who felt that their answer would also be appreciated by the MO community or (let me add) who would want to see other answers by MO users. In addition, my comment replied to an assertion that answers are given primarily for the OP's benefit, which I rebutted that by pointing out that if this were so, we would email our answers instead of posting them.

Comment: Yes, I know; you've explained your view quite clearly already.

Comment: Meanwhile, I am embarrassed that it seems that I've involved myself in a dramatic spectacle here on meta, of the sort that I have long opposed and which I believe is harmful to the site. Therefore, I apologize. I shall refrain from further involvement.

Answer (score 27):

**Disclaimer:** *I am a MathOverflow moderator. I haven't had time to carefully read through all the opinions in this lengthy debate, but I thought it would be useful to add my perspective.*

First, and I don't think anyone is denying this, there are valid reasons to migrate some questions from MSE to MO. Whether and when to do this is the question, and this is mostly an internal MSE matter. Whatever the MSE community is comfortable with will probably be fine on our side. We will gladly welcome on-topic questions from MSE (and elsewhere) and we will not be upset if you decide to keep some or even all interesting questions here rather than forwarding them to MO.

One thing that strikes me as undervalued in this discussion is the perspective of the original poster. The differences between MO and MSE are much more than just the "level" of questions. As I recently [mentioned on CSTheory](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1582/341), the answers that one would get for the same question are generally very different between MO and MSE. I tend to trust the users to choose the site they are most comfortable with. It's perfectly reasonable for a user to post a very specialized question on MSE rather than on MO because they want an MSE answer and/or they don't think an MO answer would be as useful to them. In making that choice, they accept that there may be fewer users on MSE with the required expertise to answer their question and similar consequences. That's the user's choice and it's perfectly fine. It is also perfectly admissible to ask a more elementary question on MO rather than MSE for the same reason though the MO community admittedly has a much lower tolerance for this (which I personally think is a problem on MO).

To summarize, I think that there are valid reasons to migrate questions from MSE to MO, though I don't think there should be a sharp dividing line between the two sites. I also think migration criteria should be rather conservative and respectful of the original poster's intent. Finally, I am against having some questions coexisting on MO and MSE since that would effectively prevent users from making the type of choices I described above.

Comment: I don't see how questions coexisting on MO and MSE prevents choice. The user can choose which site they are most interested in reading whether there is coexistence or not. Also what if the user's choice is to have a question coexisting.

Comment: I don't understand your final sentence about being against "questions coexisting on MO and MSE". How does that prevent said choices? Does that imply that you disagree with cross-posting - as proposed in my answer?

Comment: I hereby deny that there are valid reasons to migrate any question from MSE to MO! If you want to provide an answer to something at MO, you're welcome to replicate the question over there (since questions are CC licenced) and then answer it. But you have _absolutely no right_ to demand that the rest of us should therefore be barred from answering the question.

Comment: Barred?! Seriously? I thought it was made clear, there is no firing squad at the front page of MO.

Comment: @Asaf: You sound like a broken record now. Yes, migrating questions will mean that MSE users are not able to answer them. **Some** MSE users will be able to write an answer at MO instead, but the answer they might have wanted to write might not be acceptable at MO, **even assuming** that those users would otherwise be able to write **other** answers in a style that is acceptable for MO. And the answers would still be absent from MSE, and MSE would still be telling new askers and answerers that those questions and answers are not welcome at MSE.

Comment: vtt and Bill: That last sentence wasn't very clear. I think the "coexistence" proposal blurs the wrong line. I'm all for blurring the scope "line" between the two sites, but I really don't think we should blur the identity of the two sites in any way.

I don't think coexisting is a decision, it's an indecision. Such users just need to learn more about the options and make a decision, or flip a coin if the the options are equal. Lemon and cream are both great with tea, but not together!

Comment: @HenningMakholm: My first reaction to your comment was: lol, that guy is funny! Now I see that you didn't read beyond the second sentence I wrote... In case you haven't noticed that your extremist position doesn't hold water, consider the fact that your position assumes that your right to answer a question supersedes the poster's right to ask the question they want to!

Comment: @FrançoisG: Surely you're joking, Mr. Dorais! :-)

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais: You're making no sense at all. First you claim that there are nobody taking the postition that I have been extremely vocal about for more than a day now -- one that, I might add, currently has 22 net upvotes. Then you write some complete non-sequitur about "supersedes the poster's right to ask the question they want to" -- what on earth is that about? The poster can do _whatever he damn pleases_ for my sake -- it is _other_ people who should not be empowered to decide that the the poster must not be allowed to read answers from MSE users.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Here is a step-by-step process to enlightenment, after which you will have no further responses from me. 1) Read what I wrote. 2) Read it again. 3) Realize that I'm not claiming anything you claim I am. 4) Realize that my main point actually leans in your general direction rather than the other. 5) Take your extremist position and pour some cold water over it...

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais: You wrote: "First, and I don't think anyone is denying this, there are valid reasons to migrate some questions from MSE to MO." I am denying that, loudly and obnoxiously, and have been for some time now. You're welcome to personally think such reasons exist, but don't claim that there are nobody who think otherwise.

Comment: @François Alas, I still cannot grok your final sentence, even after your comment above. What do you mean by "blur the identity of the sites", and how does coexistence of a question on both sites do so? If you read my answer, you will see that there are very good arguments for such cross-posting, arguments that have existed since the inception of online forums (going back to the days of usenet newsgroups). It seems that you are opposed to any form of cross-posting (though I can't be sure, since what you wrote is far from clear). Nor do I see any  arguments against such.

Comment: And @Bill, I almost forgot: crossposting is fine (with the usual norms) that doesn't compromise the identity of each site.

Comment: Ok, so your "coexisting questions" does not mean cross-posted questions. So what does it mean, and how does it prevent said choices?

Comment: Bill, you're absolutely right that I haven't clarified much. I've got a lot of things going on right now, I'm sorry for not having enough time to give this discussion the attention it deserves. The "coexisting" thing is ultimately a reference to this meta.mo post by ziggurism - http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1416/2/mathoverflow-20/#Item_24 - which dragged me here in the first place.

Comment: @BillDubuque: I just read your answer more carefully. It sounds like we're saying a lot of the same things. Your answer is more about migration policy and mine is more about migration philosophy, but that just reflects our interests. Your proposal sounds fine. The actual policy details don't matter much to from the MO perspective, so long as our basic philosophies are in the same general direction there shouldn't be any serious issues.

Comment: @François Re: coexisting: Since most readers here do not read MSO, it would be helpful to clarify your answer. Indeed, even though I had read that MSE thread, it wasn't clear to me that your remark about "coexisting" posts concerns a proposal made on MSO by ziggurism. If you can find the time, please do elaborate. Do you think that most of the MSO mods would not be opposed to (well-managed) cross-posting? Re: migration philosophy, glad to hear we're in the same ballpark.

Comment: None of the mods have issues with the crossposts that currently happen between MO and MSE. (Though there is a proper way to do it.) The new possibility migrating posts between the two sites may affect this a little, but common sense always prevails. If that's the best solution for you then that will make sense to us, unless it harms us in some way (I don't see how).

Comment: Note: I've posted a more elaborate explanation of my suggestion on the meta.MO thread. I believe that ziggurism's description gave an impression that differed grossly from my intent.

Comment: @CharlesStaats: Thank you for your clarifications. As I mentioned on that meta.mo thread, it's better to continue this discussion here (or on another meta.mo thread, if that would be more relevant) since that thread is about issues directly related to MO's move to SE.

Comment: @Henning, do you not agree that if John Doe posts a question to m.se and then, sometime later, and without any outside prompting, Doe expresses a desire to see the question migrated to MO - do you not agree that that would be a valid reason to migrate a question from m.se to MO?

Comment: @Gerry: The valid reason in that case would be that if Doe really doesn't want his question to be answerable on MSE, he already has the power to delete it completely. In that case migration is the lesser of two evils.

Comment: @Henning: Unregistered users cannot delete their own questions; if there was an upvoted answer then the user cannot delete it either.

Answer (score 19):

What I am suggesting is basically an elaboration of Asaf's answer, designed to clarify a few things--especially about when questions should *not* be migrated, except--possibly--at the explicit request of the OP.

1. A question that is receiving good answers on MSE should *not* be migrated. In particular, questions should not be migrated because the MO crowd wants the question or because someone believes his/her answer would fit better on MO. [The appropriate response to the latter two situations would be--if you feel strongly about it--to re-ask the question on MO yourself, explaining that it was a question that received good answers on MSE, but that would receive a different kind of good answer on MO.]
2. A question that has not been around long enough for the MSE crowd to attempt good answers should *not* be migrated. I'm thinking the "minimum wait" should be at least a day, and possibly as much as a week.
3. A question that is not likely to receive better answers on MO should *not* be migrated.

Taking the complement of these, we have the following suggestion, which is essentially equivalent to Asaf's proposal:

**A question should be migrated if it has been around for a while (a day to a week), has not received any good answers, and is likely to receive better answers on MO.**

I would also note that a question on MO is much less likely to be closed if it was first asked on MSE and did not receive any good answers for a while. Thus, in my view, questions migrated according to this policy would have very low risk of being closed on MO.

Comment: Facts: (a) A question that is about something on-topic for MSE should not be closed as off-topic. (b) A question that is migrated to MO will be closed as off-topic. (c) No question that is off-topic on MSE is on-topic on MO. Exercise: Apply appropriate syllogisms to these facts.

Comment: I disagree with (a), in the specific case of migration to MO.

Comment: It is unfortunate that migration forces closure.  Assuming that cannot be altered, a better solution is for the OP to repost with pointers in both directions.

Comment: @Charles: Since you disagree with (a), can I infer that you do think that being "interesting to research mathematicians" makes a question off-topic for MSE?

Comment: @Henning: You can infer that I think "closed as off-topic" should be taken in context, and not always interpreted literally. The inference you attempted to draw would imply disagreement with (c); I do not disagree with (c).

Comment: @Henning, of course the choice of site is not a binary matter of on-topic/off-topic, but rather a more nuanced question of degree.

Comment: @Henning: As someone with an extensive knowledge about logic, you should be aware that reality is rather paraconsistent than described by classical logic. If anything, intuitionistic logic describes reality better, and the negation need not prove the negation of the assumption.

Comment: @JDH: Whether the software lets MSE users post answers to the question is not a nuanced question of degree, but a binary matter of open/closed.

Comment: Henning, I was objecting to your deduction that if a question is migrated, then it counts as off-topic on the original site. The content of the sites overlap, and a question can be on-topic for both sites, even if it is better-placed at one of them.

Comment: @JDH: The software feature known as "migrating" a question consists of (i) closing the question as off-topic on one site, (ii) re-posting on another site a verbatim copy of the question plus copies of already-present answers, if any, and (iii) making the closed question redirect to copy at the other site. These three parts come as a package deal. If you have something in mind that _doesn't_ involve part (i), then it's not the thing this meta question is about, as far as I understand it.

Comment: @Henning:  Our judgement of what counts as on-topic or off-topic is more nuanced than the technical software detail you are mentioning.

Comment: @JDH: That doesn't change what the software actually _does_. You can judge the question to be on-topic as much as you want; the software (having been instructed to treat it as off-topic) still won't let you answer it.

Comment: That logic would prevent us from migrating a question even when the OP and everyone agrees to it, if we felt that the question should be considered on-topic on either site. Also, your comments suggest that you would somehow lose the ability to view and answer the question after a migrating, whereas of course you could still do both these things. The software works by still showing the question, and clicking on it brings you directly to the target forum.

Comment: I agree with this. I would suggest adding "and the OP does not object to the migration". We may not need consent from the OP but I think the OP should be informed beforehand and the migration should happen *only if the OP does not object to it*. If the OP objects the question should not be migrated. Obviously this is only about questions which are on-topic on both sites but it might be good to make that explicit in the policy.

Comment: A question which is on-topic on MSE can be migrated to MO only if: 1. the migration is requested by the OP and the question is on-topic on MO, or 2. it has been around for a while (at least a week), has not received any good answers, and is likely to receive better answers on MO. The OP is informed about the possibility of migration to MO and has not objected to it.

Comment: @Kaveh: So if the OP has lost interest in the question that is sufficient reason to forbid MSE users from answering it? I completely disagree about that.

Comment: @Henning, I don't see that as forbidding anyone from answering, current users will have enough time to answer, and anyone can repost a version of the question if they want to post a particular point as an answer. The options are not dramatic as I see them, it is mostly a matter of what is more convenient for various parties in my view.

Comment: *wait a week* ... sounds about right

Answer (score 13):

*Just trying to give an alternative answer to that of Henning:*

We should recommend a migration if the question is in a rather narrow field and there are only a few not-very-active experts on MSE, while on MO there is a better chance for an answer.

We should, however, wait a day or two before migrating in case someone does answer on MSE.

Comment: Great minds think alike. :)

Comment: @Steve: We do differ in the answer. I suggest proactively migrating the question. You only suggest to offer a migration.

Comment: That sounds like a good way to ensure that we'll never get any people who can answer those questions to use MSE, because when they visit, they will find that all of the questions they care about have been shooed away.

Comment: @Henning: But many of those experts expressed in meta.MO over and over and over again that they won't come to a site with that much traffic. If they won't come here, why leave an unanswered question?

Comment: @Henning: If questions like that that are asked on MSE end up getting answered, does it really matter whether they are answered on MSE or MO?

Comment: If we cleanse away all of the questions they could have answered then **for sure** they won't start using this site. How is that a good thing?

Comment: The way SE migration works, migrated questions are considered off-topic on the originating site. This makes **forced** migration less of "you might find help over there" and more of "stop bothering us".

Comment: @Henning: If someone tells me that until I clean my house they won't come to visit, *because they are allergic to dust*, there is little to no point trying to tempt them with lucrative foods and alcohol. They just won't come. Many users on MO said that the amount of traffic deters them from here, the traffic will not decrease with time, there is no to little point hoping they will change their mind any time soon.

Comment: @LeonidKovalev: The way *most* SE sites work, CW questions are bad. *We* are different, and *MO* is even more different in these aspects.

Comment: @CharlesStaats: If you go that way, does it really matter whether MSE exists at all? People can always go elsewhere! (And they _will_, if we institute a policy of telling people who ask something that could conceivably be answered elsewhere that they should not have asked it here). Certainly I'm not going to stick around if we end up with a consensus that there's such a thing as a question that is not ignorant enough to ask here!

Comment: @Asaf: Are you seriously claiming that you have interviewed _every person in the world_ who could possibly answer the questions you want exiled from MSE, and they have **all** told you that they refuse to use MSE -- _even those who have never even heard of either MSE or MO?_

Comment: @LeonidKovalev: I suppose it depends on your perspective. For the particular migration of MSE => MO, I see this as more a compliment than a reprimand: "Your question is so mathematically difficult/sophistocated that it belongs on MO!"

Comment: @Henning: Your last comment seems more fitting to another user here; not to the rational and usually-calm barefooted Dansk.

Comment: @Henning: I guess it comes down to whether you see MO as a complementary sister sight or as a rival. Since I am much more active on MO than on MSE, I have a very different viewpoint: to the extent that I see the sights as rivals, I'm inclined to think first about what's best for MO. Since the advent of MSE, I've found that people tend to be less willing to ask accessible questions on MO, even when said questions would receive better answers there than on MSE; and I would like to see this trend reversed.

Comment: @Asaf: I take that a an acknowledgement that you in fact _don't_ know that everyone who can answer the questions you want to exile refuse in principle to use MSE.

Comment: @CharlesStaats: MO is another site for mathematical quesions, one that -- in opposition to MSE -- doesn't consider me qualified to participate there. That makes them rivals in my book, and in case of a conflict such as this I am **entirely** on MSE's side -- as everyone purporting to contribute to MSE community policy ought to be. I will object most forcefully to any plan that implies that there are questions that are _so interesting that I should not be allowed to try answering them_.

Comment: @Henning: No, you should take that as a sign I did not want to write elaborate comments from my iPhone. I also feel sad that you're reduced to such rhetorical techniques which discuss of nothing related to the content of my comment. Let me reply with the same sentiment: Have you interviewed **everyone** who has ever asked an MO-fitting question on MSE, or that ever planned to ask such question? Have you asked all those people whether or not they would have liked their question migrated if the community *showed* (say in a week) that it is incapable of providing an answer? **Have you???** :-)

Comment: @Asaf: Why would I need to do that? You're the one who is making an universal claim and using that to support a contention that I should be barred from answering questions of certain kinds.

Comment: You should read better. I did not make a **universal** claim. I said that *many* (just to clarify: not everyone, and certainly not a preposterous claim as "even those who never heard of the internet and live in isolated villages in the Gobi desert") experts which do participate on MO have expressed they very much dislike the fact that the traffic here is immense. I don't see how that would be different if there was a question they may find interesting here. They admit there are interesting questions, they just don't want to take part of this community. End of discussion.

Comment: I also **never** said that we should forbid a certain level of question. I find your reading of my opinion extremely worrisome, because it signals that others may feel the same as you. Let me express things with an analogy to cats: I wanted to adopt a cat, and I thought about picking one of the university "stray" cats. However *thinking of the benefit of the cat* I realized that living in the university is much better for the cat, they get food and company and free space they won't have in my apartment. So instead I took a cat from my brother. Do you see what is my point here?

Comment: @Henning: First of all, virtually no one seems to advocate migrating a question before the MSE community has had at least a day or two to attempt an answer. Secondly, as I understand matters, nothing prevents you from following the question to MO and answering it there, if you do have a good answer.

Comment: I would also note--emphatically--that "mathematically difficult/sophisticated" is NOT the same as "interesting."

Comment: @CharlesStaats: As I understand matters, the fact that I'm not a research mathematician means that I'm not allowed to follow the question to MO and answering it there.

Comment: @Henning: You *clearly* understand things wrong.

Comment: @CharlesStaats: I would also note that "too sophisticated for me to be allowed to answer" is every bit as abhorrent to me as "too interesting for me to be allowed to answer". Since it's a free world I cannot prevent people who thinks there are thing I shouldn't worry my puny little intellect about from congregating over at MO, I sure as hell will cry bloody murder when you come over here and try to remove the fun I have _here_. No matter whether you justify your raid as the questions being too "sophisticated" for me or too "interesting" for me.

Comment: @Henning: It means no such thing. The subject material for mathoverflow is, more or less, "things that are interesting to research mathematicians." If you can give answers and/or ask questions that research mathematicians find interesting, you are quite welcome on MO.

Comment: @Asaf: Of course I understand things wrong. After all I'm not one of the big boys who have the credentials to be allowed into the Sophisticated Questions club. How could I ever be right about anything? Clearly all the likes of me are good for is puttering around here, doing people's calculus homework for them and answering the questions that my betters decide are primitive enough to let me have a shot at!

Comment: @CharlesStaats: And since when does "thing that are interesting to research mathematicians" mean that us peons that are _not_ good enough for MO are not allowed to find them interesting too? Even though actual research mathematicians may not consider me worth listening to, I'll decide for myself what I find interesting, thankyouverymuch.

Comment: @Henning: Again, it means no such thing--you are not at all forbidden from MO. Judging someone by their lack of credentials goes very strongly against our standards as a community. If we have violated these standards in your case, then I am sorry we have wronged you so.

Comment: Henning: Just because a research mathematician finds something interesting does not mean that no other group of people can find that same thing interesting.  Otherwise I'm pretty sure that a certain book by Hofstadter would never have become a best-seller and Pulitzer prize winner.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I have the impression that your views on MO kept you from gathering the relevant information. MO is not closed to people whithout a PhD in mathemtics. I for one am a grad student in economics. In certain areas of mathematics, I do have graduate level knowledge and there is no problem asking answering questions in these areas on MO.

Comment: @Arthur: But that's what the entire thread is about. Some people are arguing that if somebody asks a question that research mathematicians find interesting, that question _ipso facto_ belongs to MO, and therefore its incarnation at MSE **should be closed**. How is that not telling MSE users that they are not allowed to find that question interesting enough to answer it?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: you are confusing two different criteria. "Interesting to research mathematicians" is the criterion for what should be *allowed* on MO. "Not answered well for a day on MSE and would probably receive a better answer on MO" is the criterion for what should be *migrated* to MO. The question of what is "allowed" on MO came up because you seem to feel that your answers would not be allowed.

Comment: @Henning: Much like those experts on MO which refuse to join MSE due to its tiresome traffic, you seem to insist that MO is a snobbish and elitist club that no one without a PhD (or a grad student) in mathematics is allowed to enter into that. You are very wrong about that, and there are several users on MO which are neither mathematicians nor have a PhD in mathematics.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: No matter who MO openly claims to be or not be closed to, the fact of the matter is that their definition of themselves is an exclusionary one: Like some other existing SE sites, their main criterion for things being on-topic there is _it must not be beneath us_. That's not the introduction to a place I would feel comfortable contributing to, no matter if I personally qualified for a letter of waiver saying that I personally am not among the excluded. And if MSE were reduced to an antechamber for that kind of community, I wouldn't be comfortable contributing here either.

Comment: This is not a response to the comments, but only to Asaf's posting.  It seems to me that migration after a few days of no answers is unproblematic.  I have done this myself, e.g., with [a question on primes](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168366/).  There is no need to judge whether or not there are experts here or there.  The lack of answers after a reasonable time is enough evidence.

Comment: @Joseph: No one disputes that if the OP can request a migration then it is a completely valid reason to migrate a question. The topic is whether or not we should migrate *without* the OP's request, and whether or not *suggest* to the OP to request migration.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke No, migration after any time *is* problematic, since it prevents the kind of pedagogical answers than can only be given here. I see no problem with duplicating the question on MO, but it should *never* be closed here, since that may prevent the OP from receiving answers at the appropriate level,  and prevents enrichments of the MSE corpus.

Comment: @Bill: That is correct. Users cannot be in *both* sites, nor they can post an answer on *both* sites. Wait, what? **You** have a user on MO?? Will it be deleted as soon as MO migrates to this network, or will you delete this one?

Comment: @Asaf That has nothing to do with what I wrote - as usual.

Comment: Yes, I tried to correct my comment but too late. I believe that reposting (with pointers to & fro) *by the OP* is the best available option.  And this is in fact what I have done several times.

Comment: @Joseph: But now that there is a migration option open, this seems like a more correct use of the software.

Comment: @Asaf: If the software impedes what is appropriate (in this case, by automatic closure), I don't think we should enslave ourselves to the software's quirks.

Comment: @Henning: I don't think there are many people advocating for the automatic migration of all "interesting" mathematical questions to MO, and here I agree with you.  But I sense some animosity directed towards MO that I do not feel is justified.

Comment: @Joseph: Perhaps you are correct. However it is a good etiquette to post only once through the SE network.

Comment: @Asaf: While Bill Dubuque's point may be stated a bit more strongly than is true, I think it is valid. If a question is on MO, an answerer typically will assume more knowledge on the part of the OP, and adjust their pedagogy accordingly--especially as regards the virtue of "conciseness" in mathematical writing.

Comment: @Arthur: Perhaps you're right that it is only "very interesting" and not merely "interesting" questions some people think MO should have an automatic monopoly on. I don't think that's much better in principle, though the quantitative impact may be less depending on where the threshold is put.

Comment: @Henning: it is not a question of "interestingness." Rather, questions more appropriate to MO tend to be those that require much more powerful mathematical machinery to solve (or perhaps even understand). The answer may be quite boring, for all that. Likewise, I can think of at least one very interesting question from the early days of MO that probably would and should be migrated to MSE if asked on MO now.

Comment: @CharlesStaats: I don't particularly care which precise term you use to characterize question you think MSE users should be denied the opportunity to post answers to. It doesn't matter whether it is "interesting", "sophisticated", "powerful" or "questions that are stated in a prime number of words" that you want a monopoly for SO on. It's the fact that you want _any group of questions at all_ that should be closed on MSE because MO wants them more.

Comment: I don't know why you say that you are unable to answer that question. It is still in the confines of the network. You're not going to need any registration, nor any special recommendation to answer a question on MO. Do you really feel that the site is more important than the content, the question or the answer?

Comment: @Henning: In my posts here, I have repeatedly opposed policies that would allow forced migration for no better reason than "MO wants them more." My primary consideration is whether the question will receive good answers; if MSE is capable of providing good answers, then those answers will often be better for the OP than answers that might be received on MO--even if it would be a good MO question.

Comment: @Charles: It seems that there are several people in this discussion which firmly believe that within the next $\omega$ years, someone might come along and be able to give an interesting answer *here*. For this chance, an answer *now* on MO is not a good idea...

Comment: @CharlesStaats: I refer you to Leonid's answer. The policy you advocate in your answer would automatically grant MO a monopoly on _interesting unanswered questions_.

Comment: I guess, in large part, it comes down to whether you view MSE and MO as places to have questions answered, or as places to answer questions. I am firmly in the former camp, both practically and philosophically. But I can understand that people who mostly come here to answer questions might come to view MSE as a resource of interesting things to think about that they do not want to see depleted. [I disagree with this view philosophically--I believe that getting questions answered should be a higher priority than maintaining a stock of old unanswered questions--but I can see the point of view.]

Comment: @CharlesStaats: It cannot be a place to have questions answered unless it is capable of attracting people who like answering.

Comment: @Charles Most general level math forums consist of a diverse mixture of both types of users, including some who wear both hats at different times. Perhaps the easiest way to accommodate these diverse viewpoints is simply to permit (managed) cross-posting. Currently it is such a small number of posts that this should not be problematic.

Answer (score 13):

The status-quo - cross-posting - may  be the most reasonable compromise. Indeed, it can actually be viewed positively, since **cross-posting promotes cross-pollination** between MSE and MO. It helps attract further expertise to MSE, and helps expose students to research-level viewpoints on MO. It permits experts to compose both multi-level expository masterpieces on MSE, and more concise research-level answers on MO, with links between the two.

For an example of the multi-level expositions that I have in mind, see William Waterhouse's beautiful article on the "Purkiss Principle", [Do Symmetric Problems Have Symmetric Solutions?](http://mathdl.maa.org/mathDL/22/?pa=content&sa=viewDocument&nodeId=2941) This won a prestigious Lester R. Ford award for expository excellence. Note how carefully crafted the exposition is - with the level of exposition *gradually* increasing throughout the article. At the start it is accessible to a calculus student. At the end, it culminates with a generalization requiring knowledge of abstract algebra and analysis (group theory and differentiable manifolds). But it is composed in a way that readers without that knowledge should still be able to gain a view of  these beautiful results beyond their knowledge horizon - intuition which may prove crucial motivation for further studies.

One of the most valuable roles of online math forums is that they provide meeting places where mathematicians are at ease speaking less-formally - filling in the gaps left in more formal communications in books and papers. MO serves this role primarily at research-level, not at the lower-levels welcomed on MSE. For example, while the final part of Waterhouse's Monthly exposition might be on-topic for MO, the introductory lower-levels would probably be off-topic on MO. Thus if we migrated a higher-level question on this topic to MO, it would be closed on MSE, which would prohibit pedagogically valuable *multi*-level expositions like Waterhouse's.

Cross-posting (vs. migration), has the benefit of leaving the question open on MSE, leaving open the opportunity to post such beautiful multi-level expositions on MSE - where they are welcomed. (Here, by "cross-posting", I mean only the simplest form - i.e. that the question stays *open* on MSE. In particular, I don't mean it to imply anything about whether or not (some) answers or comments should be duplicated across sites. That can be addressed in a separate question).

Comment: I think it is usually the other way around. One can speak more informally in an advanced setting, since everyone knows how to formalize the arguments anyways. Beginners get confused when one ignores some formal details.

Comment: @Michael I am contrasting  formal exposition in textbooks, papers, etc. vs. less formal expositions in lectures, forums, informal conversations, etc. The point is that mathematicians are often more comfortable sharing intuitive pedagogical remarks in less formal settings like MSE (as opposed to a textbook). This may be the only place that some members have easy access to such informal pedagogical remarks - esp. those outside of academia (which are surely in much higher proportion here than on MO).

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood your argument as MO not being open to informal arguments, which it certainly is.

Comment: @Michael My point seems to still be misunderstand. MSE, being general-level, welcomes a much broader class of expositions than does MO, esp. lower-level material that would be off-topic at MO (e.g. said multi-level exposition by Waterhouse). Many mathematicians would probably not feel comfortable writing expositions at lower levels on MO. But they probably would not hesitate to do so on MSE. If we migrate such questions to MO then they will be closed on MSE, which prevents such multi-level expositions from being posted on MSE - where they *are* welcomed (and encouraged).

Comment: I don't think that "formality" is a good description of the distinction between MO and MSE. In fact I think that informal comments like "with a bit of work, one can show that..." are much more at home on MO than on MSE. In my mind, the distinction is more a matter of determining which concepts need explanation, and which can be assumed. Giving a detailed explanation of something the reader understands can come across as long-winded and condescending, while throwing around concepts the reader does not understand comes across as incomprehensible and possibly condescending.

Comment: Given the number of edits to your comment "My point seems to still be misunderstood," I may well have been responding to an earlier version. This version seems more reasonable than the one I remember.

Comment: @Charles It took me a bit to realize which points were not clear. Thanks much for your help identifying such. I have edited my answer to try to remove these ambiguities.

Comment: @Charles Rereading, I see that the ambiguity was different than I first surmised. In version 1, when I emphasized that general level math forums provide excellent venues for *informal* discussions (vs. *formal* books, papers) this was not meant to imply that non-general-level forums (e.g. MO) do not. My point was  to contrast the *level* of (informal) discussions that are on-topic in each forum. Alas, that paragraph was too concise. Please ignore my prior comment about "formal" being overloaded, since that was not the source of the confusion. Hopefully version 2 of my answer is a bit clearer.

Comment: I think it's funny how we're saying exactly the same thing from opposite sides of the coin. Just a few days ago, I was explaining on CSTheory that I would sometimes rather ask a more elementary question there since a concise research-level answer suits my needs better than an "expository masterpiece", which is of course much better in other contexts.  http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1572/on-modifying-our-scope-a-proposal/1582#1582 The bottom line, of course, is that MO and MSE can, should, and will prosper even with considerable overlap in scope.

Comment: You mean multi-posting (having independent but identical or mostly identical questions asked on both sites), not cross-posting (having *the same* question appear on both sites). I don't think cross-posting is even supported.

Comment: @celtschk I don't think that there is any standardized terminology for the wide spectrum of possibilities. Yes, currently there is no support from the SE platform, so whatever we do we have to do on our own.

Answer (score 11):

This is an important issue to get right.

The two math sites are clearly different and are aimed quite
deliberately at different but overlapping populations of users,
questions and answers. The same question, were it to be posted on
both sites, would receive very different kinds of answers and
levels of attention at the two sites. It seems to me that we should develop a 
guiding policy for migration to help each question find the
home that is most suitable for it.

As an active user of both sites, I have often found questions on
math.SE that would in my opinion receive much better attention at
MO (and conversely, of course, but that is not the issue I am
discussing). Interesting but technical questions are often found here
at math.SE that end up with comparatively low views and slip
unanswered off the main page, whereas on MO these questions may
find vigorous interest and activity. Even when a question is answered here, it might have gotten more illuminating or otherwise interesting answers on MO. Although it is obvious that
the math.SE user base includes numerous mathematical experts in
diverse mathematical topics, nevertheless the user populations do
differ in aggregate and the questions I have in mind have not
found the same success here (in terms of views, attentions,
answers and votes) that I expect they would find on MO. This is a
pity.

(Some examples, found very quickly, might include: [Forcing questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/134572/413), [Generic reals in forcing iterations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/125281/413),  [Preorder of forcing notions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/97748/413), [a question on $\Delta$-system](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/99826/413),
[Comparing countable models of ZFC](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/64095/413); surely others can find many more examples. I believe that each of these questions should be migrated.)

Thus, I think we should develop a guiding policy for thinking about which questions belong on which site.

To help with this, let me begin by disagreeing with Henning's
assertion that migration should occur only at the request of the
OP. It is important for us to retain community control over this
issue, and the OP's opinion is often not the most relevant. Some
users do not realize that their question is much harder than they
expected, or out of modesty or anxiety or what have you, may post
their questions here on math.SE, but they really should be on MO.

At the very least, we should amend Henning's suggestion to also
give credence to the users who *answered* the question, since
these users also have an interest in placing their work where it
can be appreciated best.

But even more, I would say generally that we should give credence
to the community views about where such a question may belong. We
should encourage people to make comments suggesting a migration
where it is suitable, and simply allow the voting mechanism for
migration to occur as a natural process on the site.

The policy I propose is in a sense already the default policy of the site, since it is the policy that is actually implemented in the software, which allows users to vote to migrate questions. Henning's policy, in contrast, would seem to require either a software change (which seems unlikely) or else acrimonious exchanges when people vote to migrate without an OP, or with an absent OP.

Surely the boundary between the sites will evolve organically, and our ability to migrate questions will allow us to refine it. 
I propose that we think initially of the dividing line as something like the
dividing line between undergraduate mathematics and graduate
mathematics, which I take to be similar to the line between
mathematics-as-interesting-subject and mathematics-as-profession.

Comment: Surely the people who _answer_ a question would not want to be told that the question they answered is unwanted here; to have whavever rep the answer earned them taken away from them; and possibly even have their answer rejected when they try to post it, because while they typed someone has decided the question was insufficiently stupid for MSE?

Comment: It is perfectly reasonable for MSE responders to suggest that a question might have a better chance of being answered, or might get a more complete answer, on MO, but I firmly believe that the OP is the only one who should be able to make that decision.

Comment: I disagree. I have answered numerous questions here at math.SE that I would rather be at MO. It is just that I found the question while here and answered it here, because it was here.

Comment: Brian, do you also think that other users should never edit a question, or re-tag it, etc.?

Comment: **Why** would you rather that they be on MO, as long as they get decent answers? Frankly, that makes no sense to me. I don’t think that questions should be edited except to make them more readable. I don’t think that re-tagging a question is usefully analogous to migrating it.

Comment: Like many users, I write my answers for the whole community, not just the OP, and so I would rather that those answers be on MO so that the MO people can see my answer. For many of the questions I have in mind, the answer is not an answer that the OP appreciates, although the MO community would appreciate it. If only the OP mattered, we could just email our answers directly to the OP, rather than posting them at all.

Comment: Ah, well: I belong to the school that weights the OP’s needs ahead of those of the community, though I try to serve both. That is perhaps one reason that I like MSE and have relatively little interest in MO, save as a very occasional resource when I stumble across something interesting.

Comment: Brian, in addition, many math.SE questions get "decent" answers here, to use your term, but would get far better answers at MO, which the OP may not appreciate, but which many other users would. These questions should be migrated.

Comment: @JDH, are you using the royal "we"? Certainly you do not speak for me. Secondly, does the site exist "for the benefit of the questions", or for "the benefit of the users"? Who is being "guided" by your policy? That carries with it an inherent assumption of superior knowledge and wisdom. You may indeed possess these qualities in more abundance than me, but how do you know that?

Comment: @JDH: No, they most certainly should not. The user benefits from the answers here, and so do many of the rest of us. In such cases perhaps you should consider re-asking such questions yourself on MO.

Comment: David, huh?. Of course I am not using the royal "we", but rather speaking as a member of the math.SE community, proposing a view that I expect is also held by others. Of course I do not presume to speak for those who disagree with me.

Comment: @JDH There is one point I want to adress: You consider the cutoff level for MSE/MO to be undergrad/grad. My impression was that when you advocated for this view on MO meta, many opposed it. I think someone posting first year graduate analysis level questions on MO will not enjoy the experience. Set theory and logic may be different in that these areas are not yet part of standard graduate math education.

Comment: @JDH Then, what, exactly, is the antecedant of your pronoun "we"? I count as least 5 instances of its use and I have *no* idea whom you are referring to. My point is: if you are espousing your *own* views, don't buttress them with "artificial community support". Contextually, it appears as if you are putting forth that you are representing the entire community. I am a counter-example. I agree that some people may share your views, but I do not identify that group with "the community". This is particularly disagreeable in: "What we want to do.." and the multiple occurrences of "we should".

Comment: @Michael, I am proposing that merely as a rough guideline (of coure it is vague enough to stretch considerably). The MO discussion was never very clear on where the dividing line should be, and the discussion never came to a resolution, although I believe that the undergrad/grad distinction was the most commonly mentioned. In particular, this proposal was not originally mine, although I don't recall who mentioned it first. (I don't really understand the last sentence of your last comment.)

Comment: @David: The use of "we" is to suggest that *we* as a community need to define some rough guideline (which will later get refined) about what should be migrated and what shouldn't.

Comment: @David, I am sorry that you seem to object to the wording of my post. I'll try to edit it.  I said that what we want is to develop a policy on this. Don't you agree with that? Henning's proposal is one such policy. My proposal is another. If anything, my proposal is the default policy, since this is what is already implemented in the software, and Henning's policy is a deviation from the software, and will require arguments, etc. to enforce (whenever someone votes to migrate without the OP having said anything). But since you have objected to my wording, I'll try to edit it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Fair enough. What I am suggesting, is that first: the "need" itself should not be an unquestioned assumption, and secondly: there is a *world* of difference between CAN and SHOULD.

Comment: @Asaf: That’s easy: never, save with the consent of the OP. Simple, and **very** easy to implement.

Comment: @JDH I do not know that such a policy is even desirable. Perhaps enough people feel that it is, that it will come into being. As I see it, MSE is not a monolithic entity, but a diverse group of people, all of whom see its function and purpose differently. I personally believe that diversity is healthy for a community, and defining a community by "exclusion" (this doesn't belong here) carries with it certain risks. Character limits prevent me from being more specific.

Comment: @JDH: Some of your comments above appear to be advocating the ghettoisation of math.SE:  Anything that an MO user (of sufficiently high status, I'm sure) finds interesting should be migrated over there, _even if_ the answers provided by the kind folks at MO won't help the OP.  I fail to see how this could be seen as to the benefit of _the community_.

Comment: @Arthur, that's not how I view it. It would be only math.SE users who vote to migrate the questions, and these questions would  be visible (for a time) on both sites, and the community (both communities) would benefit from the interesting answers that they would gain.

Comment: @JDH, in comments above you seem to be asserting that if you find a question that you would like to answer at an MO level which you know the OP would not appreciate, then your wishes and convenience should lead to the question being force-migrated, thus preventing the OP from ever getting _any_ answers at the level of detail he wants. How on earth can you morally justify that?

Comment: "For many of the questions I have in mind, the answer is not an answer that the OP appreciates, although the MO community would appreciate it." I am inclined to agree with Arthur and Henning that migrating a question under these circumstances is questionable.

Comment: Answers to questions on MO tend to get a lot more up votes than answers on math.SE. How is a high school or beginning undergraduate who happens to ask such a question going to evaluate a situation where all the highly up-voted answers are incomprehensible and the answers she can sort of understand get very few votes?

Comment: @Jay, None of the sample questions proposed for migration are like that situation, and I doubt that the situation you describe will be anything but rare.

Comment: However, while the $\Delta$-system lemma question is certainly not likely to be asked by a high school student or beginning undergraduate, it is very clearly more appropriate for MSE than for MO, and there are quite a few people here who could have answered it easily and would have done so had you not happened to post a decent answer almost immediately.

Comment: Just a technical side note: by default the software is not going to allow migration to MO votes for ordinary users, only moderators can vote to migrate to MO. If MSE site wants to open the migration path to MO, it can ask SE to do so. But this would need support from both communities: MSE and MO. Even if we put aside the objections here, based on the discussions on MO's meta, it seems to me a considerable number of MO users would also object to the opening of the migration path from MSE to MO for ordinary users. So it seems to me that migration to MO is likely to be a moderator only action.

Comment: "So migration to MO is likely to remain ... a moderator only action." - in which case, all the more that I'd rather a migration only be done upon OP's request. Others can make a suggestion in comments (and apparently nothing more), but otherwise, I do not want to see mods *unilaterally* migrating questions to MO.

Comment: @Kaveh: I don't think most people on MO has a problem with migration path open from MSE. I think the problem might be when SO, and other non-math sites migrate things to MO instead of MSE.

Comment: @Asaf, I think they do, the issue is that they don't want people who may not be able to judge the suitability of a question for MO to migrate the question and it seems to me that most MSE users would fall in that category (right now there are 255 users who can cast close votes, how many of them can make such judgements?). I think they will go with the safer option of letting moderators decide (possibly after a discussion with an MO moderator, this is quite common between other sites.)

Comment: @Kaveh: I think that most MO users know that there are enough mathematicians here to be able and judge whether or not a question is suitable for MO. Of course others on this page argue that **no question is suitable for MO if it was posted here**, but that is the other extreme. I think that the core of users (especially those regularly browsing, or even active, on both sites) can tell whether or not migration is reasonable.

Comment: @Asaf, my impression is different from user about the opinion of MO users, but I don't see a need to discuss it right now, we will see it when (and if) MSE asks for the migration path to be opened.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Who is arguing that "no question is suitable for MO if it was posted here"?

Comment: @Asaf Seconding Henning's point. There are no "others on this page arguing that no question is suitable for MO if it was posted here". Please avoid straw man arguments. They are not constructive.

Comment: @JDH Does [your post on MSO](http://goo.gl/mGCqy) imply  you value MO more than MSE? You wrote "the existence of such a kind of level of questions on MO is important for the success of MO in the long run, and losing them to MSE hurts the operation of MO...it is important for the robust livelihood of MO to retain a greater number of those questions on MO, and to redirect them from MSE to MO. We should strongly encourage the posting of solid graduate-level questions on MO. I would suggest that the undergraduate/graduate divide is the right place to draw the line between MSE and MO" (more below)

Comment: @JDH You continued "The importance of this issue for the success of MO makes me look upon it as an argument for the transition of MO to become a stackexchange 2.0 site, or whatever it is called, provided that we had a capability to move questions from MSE to MO. For example, perhaps users could vote to kick a question from MSE to MO and vice versa, much like voting to close. This way, advanced questions on MSE would find their way to MO, and we could more easily and more finely cultivate a difference in level between the sites." ...

Comment: @JDH ... Thus, if I understand [your answer on MO,](http://goo.gl/mGCqy) you view the transition of MO to SE2 as the first step in a plan to eventually force a strict division between MSE and MO, where MSE is restricted to undergrad-level and below, and MO to grad-level and above? I suspect that any such proposal will encounter *much* opposition here. If that truly is your goal, then I think that you should make that clearer in your answer, so that folks can realize precisely what they are voting for or against.

Comment: @Bill: It seems that you missed JDH's comment on Henning's post. He decided to refrain from further involvement in this discussion (or meta altogether?).

Comment: @Asaf That's unfortunate, since it would have been interesting to hear his reasoning. It seems that some of the differences in opinions on these matters is due to weighing the concerns of one forum higher than another. The better we can understand the motivations behind such, the better we can devise a good compromise.

Comment: I see that the discussion continued a bit further without me. (I am rather disappointed to see the misrepresentations of me here as somehow hostile toward MSE; my heartfelt support for both MSE and MO is more than amply demonstrated, I feel, by what I think is my friendly and enthusiastic participation in both forums; I shall simply stand on that record.)

Comment: Meanwhile, let me summarize my view. The MO and MSE communities have overlapping memberships, but different goals and interests, and both communities benefit from this distinction. The transition of MO to SE 2.0, I had thought, would enable us all as a community (not me personally) to define and refine that helpful distinction, by moving questions from one forum to another, all of us helping each question to find its most appropriate home, much as both speakers and audience benefit when a large math conference is divided into smaller parallel sessions organized around different topics.

Answer (score 10):

I mostly agree that it'd be unusual for MSE questions to be migrated to MO.

Let me give one example of a question that I think should have been migrated.  [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65634/exercise-in-isaacss-book-on-character-theory/67470#67470) only received an answer because there was a post at meta.mathoverflow.net asking people to have a look at it.  Migrating is a better way of achieving the same goal that cross-posting did.

Comment: Why do you think migrating is *better* than cross-posting? Migrating prevents later-joined MSE members from answering the question here. We have many members who are not MO members, and they should have the right to answer it on MSE.

Comment: I think that I would be more inclined to post questions, on both MSE and MO, if it were easier and more common to migrate between them: When I had a "borderline question," I could post to one or the other and trust that the community would correct if I misjudged the level. As it is, I sometimes don't post anywhere because it is too much effort to determine which site is more appropriate.

Comment: We're talking about something that may happen one in a thousand questions.  I really don't think the harm to future users of MSE who might not get to think about this one question is comparable to the benefit to the OP of getting an answer in a timely fashion.  Cross-posting is annoying because you don't have the relevant info in one single place.

Comment: @Charles MSE's charter is to welcome *mathematical* questions at *all* levels. You need not worry about whether your MSE question is too high-level (or too low-level, or too applied, or too foundational, or too computational, etc).

Comment: @Noah The same argument works the other way too. If such questions occur so infrequently, then how can cross-posting be so "annoying"?

Comment: I'm perfectly happy to admit that this is not particularly important and none of the options are all that bad.  Nonetheless, it seems to me that migration is more convenient than cross-posting.  But it's something that reasonable people could disagree on.

Comment: Noah, the same thing happened with Yemon's other question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132775/a-sub-additivity-inequality  which I mentioned on MO Meta, George Lowther noticed, then answered here. See my April 22 post at http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1348/if-we-were-more-responsible/  where, on April 23, George said he was lurking and so on.

Comment: To be fair, I was on the verge of re-asking the question over on MO when Noah (via Will J) found and answered it.

Comment: @YemonChoi You're a stud.

Comment: @Noah: In the case of crossposts, you have the answers from the two communities visible on two different websites. That's a bit of an annoyance to cross-reference between, but ultimately doable. If instead you migrate, you have the answers from one community on their website and the answers from the other community _stuck inside their heads_ or on the personal hard drives, because the migration _prevents them from posting answers_. I don't see how having more answers at MSE can possibly be more annoying than not having them at all!

Comment: @Bill: Too often, I find myself with a question that I doubt will be well-received on MO; but I also know that I am more likely to get good answers on MO. (The answers on MSE tend to be less concise and less likely to arrive at interesting subtleties.)

Comment: Another case study could be the following question by Malik Younsi: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167498/ It received many upvotes on MSE and after five days he posted a question on MO Meta asking if it was appropriate for MO. This got the question some more attention, and people told him to re-post it on MO, but only after the bounty he just posted had expired. Finally, almost two weeks after the original posting, did the question get re-posted on MO where it got a complete answer. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/102685/

Answer (score 7):

Here is a suggestion based on [Charles' answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4889/468):

> A question which is on-topic on MSE and MO *can* be migrated to MO only if:
>
> 1. the migration is requested by the OP, or
> 2. a. it has been around for a while (at least a week),
>    b. has not received any satisfying answers,
>    c. is likely to receive better answers on MO,
>    d. the OP is informed about the possibility of migration to MO, and
>    e. the OP has not objected to the migration (in a reasonable time).

---

It seems to me there are a number of points mentioned in the discussion where different people assign different weights to them:

1. what is the best interest of the user who posted the question?
2. what is the best interest of the users who have answered the question?
3. what is the best interest of MSE community?
4. what is the best interest of MO community?

#### 4 is not important here, 2 is relevant but less important than 1 and 3:

Since this is a discussion on MSE I think item 4 should not be a main criteria. Item 2 is relevant but still less important than item 1 and 3 in my view since it is always possible to repost a more advanced version of the question on MO if one sees a need to do so and can link in both directions between questions. The only objection I see for this is that it might be less convenient for a user to repost the question and then answer it on MO, but the inconvenience can be reduced if this becomes common and acceptable on MO to post a question and an answer to it at the same time. And SE encourages those question, to the extent that now the ask page has a small checkbox which allows a user to post a question and an answer at the same time. In any case the inconvenience wouldn't justify migrating an on-topic question when it is not beneficial for neither the OP nor MSE community.

#### Item 3 is important, but secondary to 1:

The questions and answers on the site are not solely for the benefit of the OP. There are overall goals (like making the internet a better place, or increasing the mathematical knowledge, or making MSE an enjoyable place for users, etc). However normally (IMHO) the goal of OP in asking a question is receiving a satisfying answer and that should be the main criteria in deciding whether to migrate a question or not. Our goal should be helping the user to get a satisfying answer. If asking questions doesn't lead to a beneficial outcome for the OP, it will reduce the likelihood of the user asking another question and if there isn't a question there won't be any discussion about it.

It is understandable that some users may prefer to participate on MSE and would not like to participate on another site. And the point that having unanswered questions can be helpful for attracting new experts is valid. However these are not the main goals of people when they ask questions. They want answers. If you look at [the unanswered questions page](https://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?page=4&tab=votes) there aren't that many questions with high votes that are left unanswered and often they have been reposted on MO (or other sites) and have got answered there, so they are not really unanswered. So in practice this doesn't seem to be a serious issue. Moreover an upvoted migrated question is not going to be deleted, it will remain on MSE and can still attract new experts. The hypothetical feature situations are not very helping in making decisions about policies. Yes, it is possible that a new user will come some day and answer an unanswered question, but how often does that happen? I mean how many of questions got answered by a new user after remaining unanswered for 1 year? My guess is that not that many. So I think if a question is not answered in a month it is unlikely to get answered here (it would be good to know the actual statistics). And in the worst case, if an MSE user still wants to add something after migration on MSE they can repost a more advanced version of the question and answer it (in a similar way that an MO user can repost as described above).

#### Will migration make the site less interesting?

I also don't think migrations will make the site uninteresting. The unanswered questions are not the only interesting part of the site. At least for me reading answers here is more enjoyable than reading unanswered questions. And the interesting questions will keep flowing and getting answered. And there will always be some interesting questions that are unanswered if the period between asking and migration is long enough. How long? Long enough to make sure that a typical MSE user has enough time to read and answer the question. I don't think there is any hurry for migration so a week (or maybe two) should be reasonable IMHO.

#### Migration may increase the number of interesting questions!

Finally, I think the possibility of migration for unanswered question from MSE to MO can in fact increase the number of interesting questions on MSE in place of reducing them. If I know that my question can be migrated to MO if it remains unanswered it makes me more likely to ask the question on MSE, particularly when I have doubts about its suitability on MO. I can ask it here, if it gets answered then I am happy. And if it doesn't get answered in a reasonable time it can be migrated to MO and it would be much less likely to be closed as off-topic on MO since there is actual evidence that it is not an easy question. (I already do this between CS.SE and cstheory.)

Comment: If I could upvote twice, I would!

Comment: As for (1), if the OP wants to ask his question on MO, and MO wants to allow him to do that, they should provide him with a way to _ask the question there_ that does not involve removing it from MSE. It is not the task of MSE to be an antechamber for MO where questions can be posted while MO contemplates whether they want them or not.

Comment: As for (2), it is the best interest of the users who answered the question on MSE that their answer is not removed from MSE and their rep earned by them is not taken away from the. It is the best interest of users who might later want to answer the question on MSE that they be allowed to do so.

Comment: As for (3), it is clearly in the best interest of the MSE community that we don't tell potential _askers_ that such-and-such questions are not welcome here, simply because they have sat for a while, and it is in the best interest of the MSE community that we don't tell potential _answerers_ that answers to such-and-such questions are not welcome here.

Comment: @Henning, let me shortly reply, starting with simpler ones: regarding 2, the policy is about *unanswered* questions, so I don't think removing reputation is a concern. And if the period between asking and migration is long enough the MSE users will have time to answer the question if they want and can. (Hypothetical feature users who are not MSE users at the moment is not a major concern in m view as I wrote in the answer.)

Comment: @Henning, regarding 1, it is not about MO, it is about OP. The OP may want to first post the question on MSE or may not be aware of MO or suitability of the question there. You seem to agree that migration can be acceptable if the OP ask for migration, I don't think that this is much different from that situation (i.e. your points would apply to that situation also).

Comment: @Kaveh: I'm okay with the OP asking for migration because it is not worse than the OP deleting his question here (which he can already do) and then reposting it manually on MO. But that's just a practical matter -- author-initiated deletions are for questions that the author has been convinced are _bad questions_. Questions that turn out to be unexpectedly _good_ should not be closed or deleted at MSE if I had my say. The OP is free to _also_ post them on MO if he wants to, and I would not object to a software "clone this question on MO" feature, if only it did not close the question here.

Comment: @Henning, regarding 3, I completely agree with your intention, we should find a way that will not give such an impression. However I think this can be done through other means to reasonable extent. E.g. by not migrating questions too early, informing the OP about the migration, and avoiding doing so if the OP objects (so the OP has the final say over the issue), by avoiding migrating answered questions, etc.

Comment: @Kaveh: Your proposal are about "questions that have not received any _satisfying_ answers within some time". Who is to decide what is satisfying? And what if the question doesn't receive any satisfying answers on MO within that period of time? Will we get the question back, then, or does MO get to hoard all of the _really_ good questions? Hypothetical future users who are not MSE users at the moment **are** my concern. If they take a look here and find that the most interesting questions cannot be answered here, do you think they are going to _become_ MSE users (is they qualify for MO)?

Comment: @Kaveh: I don't see how what you present as mitigations to (3) address the problem _at all_. None of these efforts are going to change the fact that the questions are then not answerable on MSE anymore.

Comment: @Henning, reposting can be a possibility, however there are also issues with it. I think a reasonable implementation of a reposting policy should require the OP to maintain the copies, I think it is more annoying to see an unanswered question on MSE which is not really unanswered but no one is posting an answer to it because it is answered somewhere else. It will need a higher effort from the OP. I think we can see this as a trade-off between the work that an OP will do and the work a person who wants to answer a migrated question would need to do. I am leaning towards less effort for askers.

Comment: @Henning, that is true that the original copy is unanswerable (unless a moderator unlocks and reopens the question, which can be done independently from MO). However I don't think it will have a significant effect on potential askers and answerers if we keep the question here for a long enough time before migrating and etc.

Comment: @Kaveh: You don't think it will have a significant effect on a potential answerer that he gets told "to answer this question you need to create an account on MO" or "you can answer this question with an MSE account". Which of those two messages do you think is likely to make the potential answerer becoming an MSE user? Not to mention: which of those two messages to you think would make a potential answerer _who is not a research mathematician_ comfortable with answering the question _at all_?

Comment: @Henning, your point about how to determine if a question has not received a satisfying answer is valid. One can think of it as when the question does not have any upvoted answers (possibly also when the OP explicitly states that the answers are not satisfying). I think something similar addressing your concerns should be possible.

Comment: @Kaveh: As I said, I would not oppose a software feature that automatically cloned a question on MO and automatically inserted links back and forth. If the two copies diverge, then I don't see how MO is worse off than if the answers on MSE had not been allowed to exist at all. And from MSE's side, having the question here is certainly better than not having it here.

Comment: @Henning, yes, I don't think [it](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4880/what-when-and-will-we-migrate-questions-to-mo-2-0/4903#comment19332_4903) will have a significant effect. But I don't have any statistics to argue objectively about it.

Comment: @Kaveh: I wish I could understand which concerns of _yours_ that can apparently only be addressed by preventing MSE users from posting answers to certain questions. If I could understand what bad thing would follow from a late-arriving answer being posted by an MSE user after the question has been posted on MO too, perhaps I would be able to find something that could address those concerns of yours.

Comment: @Henning, closure of a migrated question is a SE "feature" and they have reasons for it (I think they were not thinking about posts which can be on-topic on several sites when they designed most of the software, would they change it now? I feel it is not very likely). One possibility is to reopen the question after migration to get two copies but similar to [what I wrote above](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4880/what-when-and-will-we-migrate-questions-to-mo-2-0/4903#comment19330_4903) IMHO it would still need the effort on OP's part to maintain them.

Comment: @Henning, I don't have any concerns that can only be address by preventing MSE users from posting answers. My concern is regarding maintaining multiple copies of the same question. If that can be done effectively I don't see any reason not to keep an open copy on MSE after migration.

Comment: @Henning, as a theoretical computer scientist, significant means there is a constant $c>0$ s.t. $\mathsf{Pr}[Event_n] > \frac{1}{n^c}$ for infinitely many $n$, where $n$ is the problem size. :)

Comment: @Kaveh: But what if we _don't_ maintain the two copies in perfect synchrony? The worst that can happen is that MSE will contain answers to a slightly different question than a question on MO. How can that conceivably be a _worse_ outcome than those answers-to-a-slightly-different-question not existing at all?

Comment: @Henning: I don't understand your view that the questions that would get transferred are inherently somewhat more interesting. Most questions n MO are quite boring to most research mathematicians. These are questions for a very specialized, small audience, much smaller than "all research mathematicians". There are actually lots of complaints on MO meta about this trend.

Comment: @Henning, the problem is similar to the problem about cross-posting: cross-posting duplicates effort and fractures discussion, a reader may be unaware of the answers/comments/clarification that has happened on another site, essentially missing a large of the information about the question. I personally don't like answering a question which has been answered sufficiently on another site and my impression is that there are others who feel similarly. In short, unmaintained copies means more effort for readers and potential answerers and IMHO that is worse than requiring more effort from OP.

Comment: @Henning, assume that you post an answer and the OP replies that they have clarified the question on another site and your answer is not relevant to what they are asking. To avoid such situations the readers would need to check the copies to make sure we are not missing any important information about the question. I find it annoying and a waste of time to go to another site and reread the copy there to make sure I am not missing any significant information about the question. And any reader who is interested in the question would need to do this so much more work than the other options.

Comment: @Kaveh: I don't see how a solution that carries a risk of such problems is conceivably worse (for me, or for anyone else) than a solution that _guarantees_ that I won't be allowed to post an answer at all. If given a choice between the chance to answer a potentially out-of-date question, and _no chance to answer it_ at all, I find the first option _unambiguously_ superior.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: As long as there is _some_ intersection between interesting questions and questions that MSE users are not allowed to post answers to, harm is being done. One doesn't need to be a subset of the other for the harm to MSE to arise.

Comment: @Kaveh: "I personally don't like answering a question which has been answered sufficiently on another site and my impression is that there are others who feel similarly" -- since I'm okay with crosslinks between the two questions (possibly even automatically generated), nothing stops you from checking whether the question has already been answered on the other site before you write yours. On the other hand, you solution _would_ prevent me from answering the question _no matter whether it has an answer anywhere or not_.

Comment: @Kaveh: And if you're concerned about "effort for potential answerers", then I'm going to ask you again: _What about potential answerers who are not research mathematicians_?

Comment: @Henning: You seem to have eight accounts on the SE network. Getting a ninth account shouldn't be that big of hurdle. If you are not willing to post there because you think everyone there are arrogant snobs, that's fine. But it is strange to say you *can't* answer a question after it is moved to MO.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: The eight accounts I have are all on sites with open participation policies. In contrast, MO is an exclusive forum, defined as being for "things that are interesting to research mathematician". Consequently, even though the software will let me create an account there, I can't actually (in good faith) _post_ there without first finding a research mathematician and getting him to certify that what I'm about to post is within the scope of the site -- because the scope of the site is explicitly defined by the subjective tastes of a group of people that doesn't include me.

Comment: Since my personal circle of acquaintances includes zero research mathematicians, that would be a rather big hurdle for me to clear. Well, I suppose I could ask it as a question on MSE: "Is the following text worthy of being posted at MO?"

Comment: @Henning Now things are getting absurd. If that were the only means, every research mathematician would need to find another research mathematician to confirm that something is of interest to research mathematician*s* before posting on MO. A more enjoyable way to gather information on what is apprpriate on MO is browsing MO. You might actually see something you like there.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: By the way I have no way to judge whether the _people_ on MO are arrogant snobs. Probably they are not; most people in general aren't. The _site concept_, on the other hand _is_ elitist and exclusionary.

Comment: @Kaveh This does not solve the problem raised in my answer. By migrating, the question would be closed on MSE, so we would completely lose the capability to post such highly pedagogically valuable multi-level answers. This is too high a cost to pay. Moreover, it could lead to a sharp divide in level between MO and MSE, which would probably cause many experts to leave. Again, far too high a price to pay. For forums with overlapping scope, cross-posting is the only reasonable solution.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: Of course not. A research mathematician who wants to post something on MO can do so immediately because _he_ is a research mathematician and _he_ finds it interesting, and _therefore_ it is on topic. Their FAQ says "at least one". The point is that _by their own definition_, I am constitutionally unable to judge whether something is on-topic there.

Comment: @Henning: People make judgements all the time about what will be interesting to other people whose interests diverge from their own--for instance, when selecting gifts. I think this is the spirit in which the MO FAQ are written. Certainly, a research mathematician will not feel free to post anything at all on MO if he finds it interesting; he will try to predict whether it will be interesting to other research mathematicians. Making such predictions is harder for someone who is not a research mathematician, but not impossible.

Comment: @Henning: I still find the animosity you direct towards MO quite perplexing.  Do you have the same feelings towards [cstheory.SE](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)? [academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com/)? [libraries.SE](http://libraries.stackexchange.com/)?  Should math.SE stop migrating any questions to these other exclusionary and elitist sites?  (Okay, migration to libraries.SE is a bit of a stretch, but cstheory.SE clearly overlaps.)

Comment: @Henning: From the [MO faq](http://mathoverflow.net/faq): "There are several broad categories of questions that should not be asked on MathOverflow. ... If your question is closed, _please don't take this to mean that you are not welcome on the site, or think that this will be held against you in the future_. A lot of active users have had questions closed at one point or another."  (emphasis mine)

Comment: @Henning: In the Wikipedia entry about von Neumann it says he was a big fan of Byzantine history, and supposedly knew more about it than experts on the field. If he were alive today, do you think he would refrain from posting on a site dedicated for Byzantine history researchers - just because he happens to be a mathematician? There is no fire squad on MO shooting every non-mathematician person posting on the site. The worst case is that your post will be closed, the best case is that it will generate six highly voted answers and two papers.

Comment: @Asaf: What you seem to me saying is that von Neumann _was_ a Byzantine history researcher, even though he may not have earned an income being one. Of course, then, he would be welcomed on a site specifically dedicated to a group he was a prominent member of.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't what I said. I just said he liked it and knew a lot on the topic. I am also sure that you know about logic a lot more than some of the experts on MO (maybe not the logicians, but probably more than people whose expertise is in hard analysis for example). If you think that von Neumann had a place in byzantine.SE, I don't see why you belittle yourself so much that you think that you have no place in MO. There are several users on MO which are not researchers at all, no one is making their life difficult for that.

Comment: @Arthur: My feelings towards cstheory.SE are exactly the same; the other two I don't know enough about to have an opinion. My position is that questions that are already on-topic where they are _should never be migrated_ from an all-levels-welcome site like MSE to a restricted-audience one. // The fact that I might not be _personally_ unwelcome on MO provides no relief if the _answer_ I would have posted on MSE _is_ unwelcome on MO (because I don't write like a research mathematician -- I don't know enough to pepper my answers with up-to-date literature citations, for example).

Comment: @Asaf: Again, even if I were provided with personal "tolerated guest" status on MO, I could never be a _member_ of that community -- because that community is _explicitly defined_ by the interests of a specific set of people that excludes me. Such a definition would implicitly make me a second-class citizen there no matter how welcoming the behavior of the _people_ making up the community.

Comment: @HenningMakholm There are also MO-answers that would get downvoted at MSE. On MO I can write as an answer "That follows from theorem 4 in the following paper in the Kazhakstan Journal of Mathematics.." On MSE I would have to carefully explain it provide intuition etc. In terms of answers, MSE is rather less welcoming.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: So either site would reject some answers that the other one welcomes. Is that somehow an argument that it would be a good thing to insist that one of the sites _must_ not allow answers of its own to it? I don't see it.

Comment: Henning, aren't your loud comments throughout this discussion a bit overblown? I urge you simply to create an MO account and start participating there, if those are the kinds of questions and answers that interest you (your objection about being constitutionally unable to do so notwithstanding). In addition, your repeated claim that math.SE welcomes questions at all levels is not really true (despite the FAQ), since the highly technical questions in question typically receive low views, low votes and few answers here. Clearly, they are not really appreciated here.

Comment: @Michael: I have seen answers of that type not just upvoted, but accepted at MSE. Whether you would have to provide intuition, etc., depends very much on the nature of the question and what can be reasonably inferred about the knowledge base of the OP.

Comment: @JDH: I fail to see how ‘low views, low votes and few answers here’ is an indication that such questions are not really appreciated here. This is a diverse group. Whether the part of it that is the audience for a particular question or type of question is large or small is independent of the extent to which it appreciates the question or type of question.

Comment: @Brian, if you went to a party where most people ignored you and few spoke to you, but next door was another party full of people wanting to interact with you, then I would say you were not really appreciated at the first party in comparison with  the second.

Comment: @JDH: I don’t go to parties to have questions answered. In the relevant context **one** adequate interaction is sufficient.

Comment: @Michael: I don’t share Henning’s extreme animosity towards MO, and I do have the formal credentials, albeit they’ve been gathering rust for many years, but I frankly don’t feel comfortable at MO and have no desire to participate. It does (to me) have a bit of the feel of an old boys’ club, and I’ve seen comments here and elsewhere that suggest that I’m not alone in this.

Comment: @Brian: There's no "extreme animosity" here. I just recognize MO as a club that has defined themselves as being _not for me_. That is fine. I just won't have them coming over here and dictating what I can and can't do _outside_ their club.

Comment: @Henning: Perhaps I should have said *apparent extreme animosity*; it actually has come across that way even to me, and my view on migration is pretty much the same as yours.

Comment: @Bill, sorry for late reply. It took me sometime to read the comments. As said to Henning, I don't see the decision as dramatic. If a user wants to post an answer to a migrated/closed/... question they can still post a new version of it and answer that. Same applies to people who want to have their their answers on MO. I think this is mostly about what is more convenient to different parties. My view is to have least work for reader, lesser work for the OP, more work for those who may want to post an answer to a migrated question that remained unanswered for a considerable period of time.

Comment: @Bill, I think this is more optimal and better for the users in general and MSE community. You and Henning lean towards more work for the OP (in case OP maintains copies) or for the readers (in case OP does not maintain copies). Whichever policy we adopt everyone can still do the things they want, it just may require more work on the part of some users. (I think your other concerns in the comment can be addressed and doesn't imply an anti-migration policy, and I have explained my view towards them in my answer and comments above.)

Comment: @Kaveh I don't agree that reposting new versions of migrated-and-closed questions is a viable solution. Potential answerers may never even see the question after it is closed, due to lower exposure of closed questions. Further, they may not feel comfortable reposting the question then answering it, nor should they have to jump through such hoops to do so. Also  migration may send incorrect messages to the community - that such topics are not welcome here, when in fact they are. Our goal should be to implement policies that help *attract* (not *repel*) further expertise.

Comment: I don't know if this is the place to say it, but here goes: MO is not a monolithic organization. There is a great diversity of opinion there on how wide a variety of questions and answers should be welcomed. There are questions that get closed, and re-opened, and closed again, as one group or another gets the upper hand. So if anyone here has ever been made to feel unwelcome at MO, it's possible that you just ran into the hothead faction on a bad day. Please don't judge the whole of MO by the actions of an unrepresentative few.

Comment: @Bill, yes, but my point is it is possible (really possible). So the issue is convenience, your suggestion is less convenient for some users, my suggestion is less convenient for some other.

Comment: @Bill, ps: I don't think migration will *necessarily* send any wrong message about MSE, if we are careful in the implementation we can avoid such things (as I explained before). You may have a different view that it is not possible and I respect that. But simply repeating the claim is not going to change my view. If you have statistics or other evidence to support the claim please provide them, otherwise it is matter of opinion. My experience on cs.se shows that experts do not leave the site, in fact my impression is that we get more and more people participating from cstheory on cs.se.

Comment: @Bill, I participate on MO and cstheory as a researcher, I participate on MSE and CS.SE as a teacher, and others do also, so IMHO the concern about loosing experts to MO because of migration is exaggerated. I don't see evidence to support it and in the case that really happens we can revisit the migration policy in after a few months and change it to address the issue.

Comment: @Kaveh Please write more clearly. I have no idea what "yes, but my point is it is possible" refers to. Nor do I have any clue what claims that you think I have repeated, since you don't say (nor do I see any). I don't have statistics, but I do have a complex neural network accumulating over three decades of experience in general-level math forums.  Finally, I don't agree that the differences in our viewpoints boils down to trivialities such as matters of convenience for users.

Comment: @Bill, Sorry, I was replying to your comment part by part. It in "it is possible" refers to "possibility of posting answers to migrated questions on MSE". The claim [you repeated](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4880/what-when-and-will-we-migrate-questions-to-mo-2-0/4903#comment19357_4903) is that migration will have a negative effect on MSE, sending incorrect messages and causing experts to leave. You have your experience, I have a different one, the discussion over the issue will not lead anywhere if the arguments are based on general personal experiences.

Comment: @Bill, I think it does mostly boil down to convenience as I explained. Each suggested policy makes life less convenient for some users and more convenient for some other users. No one is forbidding anyone from reposting a question they want to answer, so they can answer the question if they want to. You assign more value to the convenience of potential future experts who may want to answer a migrated question more, I assign more value to the convenience of the current users who ask questions and read them.

Comment: @Bill, I don't think I have anything more to say if you don't agree that the anti-migration policy will make life less convenient either for users who ask questions or for users who read them.

Comment: @Henning: I actually don't see much difference between MO restricting its domain of discourse to mathematical questions of a more advanced nature, and math.SE restricting its domain of discourse to _real_ mathematics, as opposed to numerology, accountancy, or even philosophy of mathematics.  In order to achieve some sort of coherency every SE site defines itself based on the types of questions they deem "acceptable".  Further, I urge you to look at [this recent MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/104699), posed by a self-described neophyte, and see if it might be up your alley.

Comment: @Arthur: After thinking it over I think what offends me about MO is this: Consider the groups A={x|x likes mathematics}, and B={x|x is a professional research mathematician}. MO is for people who identify more with group B than with group A -- not all people at MO may _themselves_ be in B, but the moral price of admission is accepting the value proposition that B is the more important predicate. That feels to me a like a kind of treason to the universal and democratic character of mathematics. Even though MO may have things "right up my alley", I'm not willing to pay that price.

Comment: (And, frankly, my opposition to migration is in large part due to the fact that it would function as a way to coerce people into accepting the MO value proposition -- that some topics are only available to people who accept that).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Your division cannot be true. There are enough people in both MO and MSE. So posting at one place doesn't make one identify more with that group. I feel more at home at MSE, but for some questions, I prefer to rely on the expertise present at MO. I've counted once at least seven Fields medalists at MO. I am happy that I can benefit from such an even more selective group I clearly do not belong to.

Comment: @HenningMakholm It also seems to me like you are opposed to M on principle grounds. That might be legitimate, but I don't think the relations between sites on the stack exchange network should be defined by one of the sites not being viewed as having a right to exist.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: Certainly they have a _right to exist_. I just don't think the right to answer certain questions _posted and on topic here_ should be limited to people who are willing to accept the MO value proposition.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: You're welcome to decide that you can personally tolerate interacting with the Fields-medalists-who-refuse-to-associate-with-the-rabble in order to receive the benefit of their answers. I don't think you ought to decide that only people who share that willingness should be allowed to answer certain questions.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: Also I don't think your argument from an overlap between the user bases holds. There is nothing that prevents from someone who identifies themselves primarily with B from _also_ posting at the site for all of A sometimes.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: But seriously, why are you mad?  Professional mathematicians generally don't like looking at easy highschool/undergrad homework that just clutters things up.  I don't see why you think that it's snobbish for a mathematician to find some questions beneath him?  MO is not an exclusive gated community.  It's more like the pro-circuit in tennis, where a certain level of play is expected for participation.  I feel like you're purposely being dense here.

Comment: @HarryGindi: I have no trouble with professional mathematicians not wanting to deal with "too easy" questions. We all have criteria for what we personally find interesting. What I take issue with is the professional mathematicans who decide that _therefore_ they don't want their writings to even appear on the same site that _also_ contains uninteresting easy questions. Why not just ignore questions they are not interested in -- are they afraid they will get undergraduate cooties on their lofty writings or what?

Comment: I suspect the issue we're all dancing around here is reputation. A hypothesis would be that those professional mathematicians refuse to answer questions on MSE not because of undergrad cooties, but because it won't earn any MO reputation for them here. But if we're going _there_, then I certainly think I'm entitled to object to a policy implying that this-or-that question is so advanced that nobody must be allowed to earn MSE rep for answering it.

Answer (score 4):

My first instinct was that there will be some advanced questions that are better at MO.

However after reading Henning Makholm's vocal opposition to this idea, I think that questions should only be migrated to MO if the OP agrees to it.

If it is suggested to an OP that their question might get more answers (or get answered at all) at MO, but the OP does not consent then the question should stay put. However if this happens then I think any other interested party should feel free to cross-post the question themselves if the OP is not interested in cross-posting.

Answer (score -1):

It has been suggested here a few times that posts could be in some way double-posted in both communities. Another place where this has come up with overlapping sites is Christianity vs Biblical Hermeneutics. There, the consensus of the moderators of both sites is that it is perfectly acceptable to ask the same question in both places, but *it should not be word-for-word identical*. When the question is reposted on the second site, it should be rewritten for the target audience.

There has even been at least one case of a question which was asked on Site A, migrated to Site B, and then asked again (in different, more appropriate, form) on Site A.

Comment: I do not think questions should be asked in math.SE and MO simultaneously. It fractures the audience and encourages duplication of effort.

Comment: @Carl I agree. But it is fine to ask a question that has been answered on on Mo on a level too high on MSE.

Comment: Agreed..........

Comment: I would also add that if one asks the question first on one site and then later on the other (for whatever reason), there should be no reason to change the wording unless this is to reflect new understanding on the askers part or similar.

Answer (score -2):

*Separated out into a separate answer to mitigate confusion about the meaning of votes:*

We *also* should never even tell anyone in comments that they should have been asking their question on another site, if the question they actually asked is on-topic here.

Comment: While I cannot say I agree with the other answer, I can surely say that I strongly disagree with this answer. Are we not telling people about MO today? Why should we stop doing that just because MO joins the SE network?

Comment: I think we should stop telling people to go away _independently of_ whether MO joinse SE or not.

Comment: Henning, I think that when people ask questions in a particularly narrow field of interest in which there *more* experts on MO than the occasional expert passing through MSE - then we surely need to recommend another site. Much like when someone asks me a question about C*-algebra I don't insist on trying to answer, I direct him to the next office where someone that can actually answer him sits.

Comment: I don't see a conflict here. Henning doesn't want to tell people what they *should* do. Asaf wants to tell people what they *can* do. These can co-exist peacefully - telling someone a question might get better answers at MO is not the same as telling someone the question ought to have been sent to MO instead of to m.se.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I don't think that distinction can be reliably communicated to new users. _"Sorry -- I will delete my question at once!"_ appears to be a not uncommon response from new users to even the most tentative suggestions that another SE site "might be better" for their question. One can hardly fault the new user for that misunderstanding. Thus, I think such suggestions _should not be made_, unless accompanied with _extremely explicit assurances_ that the question _is_ on-topic here too.

Comment: "You should _also_ post this on MO." That seems to convey the right message. Even friendlier tones are possible: "That's an interesting question, one that the researchers on MO might also find interesting. You should cross-post this to MO to see if anyone there can answer." Many users have cross-posted before. The talent level on both sites is very high, but there are specialists that only visit one site. (I'm shocked by the big names I see here, but really shocked by the MO population!) Anyway, it seems wrong to not direct the user to the valuable resource that is MO, when appropriate.

Comment: Also, I don't think such a suggestion is going to be made by a non-MO user. So, it seems likely that the suggestion, when it is made, will tend to be appropriate. Users occasionally getting the wrong impression and deleting a question is not as great a risk as users remaining unaware of a potentially valuable resource.